# SELECT ... IN to duplicate records in resultset?

Tags: mysql, sql

Do you know how to write a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN ( 1, 3, 1, 1 )
```

to return also the records that are duplicate (ie: 3 customers with id 1)?

another question - is there a way I can get the records sorted by the order of the ids in the IN clause?

Edit:
The ID is PK, there are no multiple records with the same ID. I want the resultset to contain the record with ID 1, multiplied 3 times

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the IDS that build up your in clause?

Comment: IMO this kind of logic shouldn't be in a query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you insert the list entries into a (temporary) table? if so

```
select c.* from customers c join #tmp t on c.id = t.id
```

To solve the ordering you'd need insert them in order with an ascending numeric value e.g. 'rank'

```
select c.* from customers c join #tmp t on c.id = t.id order by t.rank
```

Answer (score 1):

for your first question this should work: `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN (1, 3);` it will return all customer that have id=1 or id=3 no matter how many are there share same id.

for second question:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN ( 1, 3) Order By Field(id,1,3);
```

Values in Field should be same as in IN clause.

Comment: Please see my edit (i added some further details/specifications/observations )

Comment: @Tudor: do you want same rows displayed 3 times?

Comment: @Tudor: then you already get answers from @Andomar and @lastfish.

Comment: that is right - I just want to wait a little more, to see if there are other ideas regarding thid problem (besides making n queries from application side).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 customers with the same id, you have bigger problems (assuming id is the PK). You will run into some data integrity issues at some point.

Comment: Please see my edit (i added some further details/specifications/observations )

Comment: doing a UNION SELECT would be one option. But it is not a clean solution. SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN ( 1, 3) UNION SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN ( 1) UNION SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN ( 1). Again - this is probably not the clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could build an inline table, and `join` it to the base table:

```
SELECT  cust.* 
FROM    (
        select  1 as id
        union all
        select  3
        union all
        select  1
        union all
        select  1
        ) as ids
LEFT JOIN
        Customers cust
ON      ids.id = cust.id
```

Comment: this might be an interesting ideea. Also, I thought about creating a temporary table, create records in it with my ids and then do a JOIN with customers. I am looking for something simpler - if that is possible

Comment: I accepted lastfish's response because he's at the beginning on the site, having less than 100 reputation - although, I promoted your answer too. Thank you for your opinion

Answer (score 0):

HI, if your id in table is primary key then there is no way to have more customers with id, but in case its not than it will return all customers with id=1

Comment: no, I don't have multiple records with that ID - I just want the same record multiplied 3 times